# HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository can't find SecurityContext despite it is accesible via SecurityContextHolder.getContext()

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jaas

I'm working in an application that uses Spring Security (ver. 3.2.3) and Jaas.
To get this, basically we've added a custom filter that extends J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter. It works fine for simple filters:

```
<http pattern="/intern/**" auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"
    entry-point-ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter ref="myJ2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter" before="FIRST" />
    <csrf />
</http>
```

But for secured controller methods like this:

```
@Secured({ ROLE_RIGHT_ADMIN })
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public SearchResult getAll(SearchParams searchParams) throws ModelException {
    return getService().searchEntities(searchParams);
}
```

Spring returns forbidden, 403.
Making some debug and code diving we found that one of the filters, HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository, cant find the security context. The code is the folowing:

```
// Session exists, so try to obtain a context from it.

Object contextFromSession = httpSession.getAttribute(springSecurityContextKey);

if (contextFromSession == null) {
    if (debug) {
        logger.debug("HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
    }
    return null;
}
```

But the security context is created fine and stored. Also when i debug the code i'm able to reach the security context inside HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository using:

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext()`

So, whats the problem with this SecurityContextPersistenceFilter and the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository?

**Note:** I've make a workaround, storing manually the context where HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository is going to look for it.

Comment: Are you sure you have `<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />` setted in your security `xml` config file?

Comment: Yes, without it it will not fail because the controller method wouldn't be secured.